# Найти число в 8 раз меньше заданного не использую деления и сдвиги на Си

Tags: c

Не понятно, возможно ли вообще сдвинуть число, не используя <<, >> Например, с помощью операции И можно младшие три бита превратить в ноль, но как обрезать данные три нуля, не используя сдвиги совсем не понятно

Comment: Да поделите на 8!

Answer (score 0):

Битовые операции без сдвигов, умножений и делений:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    unsigned n;
    scanf("%u", &n);

    unsigned m = 0;
    for (unsigned b8 = 8, b1 = 1; b8 != 0; b8 += b8, b1 += b1) {
        if ((b8 & n) != 0) {
            m |= b1;
        }
    }
    printf("%u\n", m);
}
```

Comment: Интересный эффект с взаимосвязью операций сложения, вычитания, умножения и деления. Процесс не всегда обратим.

Comment: @rotabor, деление всегда выражается через умножение, умножение и вычитание через сложение, сложение через инкремент. Если забыть об эффективности, для арифметики достаточно равенства и инкремента на единичку. Другими словами, можно разделить два числа пользуясь только нулём, инкрементом и равенством. Ноги растут из [арифметики Пеано](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE).

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что умножение числа на 2 (или любой другой множитель) можно заменить сложением, а вот деление на 2...